# Stata. How to match values in 1:m relationship?

Tags: merge, stata

I have two data sets. First one is:

```
countyGroup income  other_data_
    1       20990   …
    2       25622   …
    3       24289   …
    4       27391   …
    5       23326   …
    6       19261   …
    7       15197   …
    8       11132   …
```

The second one is:

```
countyGroup state   county  other_data
    1       IL      123     …
    1       IL      123     …
    2       MI      365     …
    1       IL      123     …
    3       AK      65      …
    4       IL      546     …
    5       MI      689     …
    6       AK      32      …
```

Variable `countyGroup` uniquely identifies both `state` and `county`. The second data set contains `countyGroup`, `state` and `county`. The first data set contains only `countyGroup`. I need to generate two variables (`state` and `county`) in the first data set.

I tried to match the values using `merge`:

```
use dataset1
merge 1:m countyGroup using dataset2, keepusing(state state cntyfp) update replace
```

The result that I get is the duplicate rows...I tried `1:1` it did not work...I can always `drop` those duplicate rows, but I wanted to merge them correctly from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to know about the duplicate rows (Stata's term is "observations"). If they are identical on all variables, there is no extra information, and it's cleanest and simplest to use `duplicates drop` to get them out of the way before the `merge`.

`duplicates` is a general tool for managing duplicates.

If there is different information on the other variables, tell us more about what that is and your goals here.

(LATER) With your datasets you posted

```
   merge 1:m countyGroup using dataset2
```

seems to work fine.

Comment: The two initial data sets DO NOT contain duplicate observations. However, ones I merge them the way I showed above, the resulting data set will have duplicates.

Comment: What you are showing includes duplicates on your first three variables in the second dataset. If the observations differ on the other variables, what is the problem precisely? If they don't differ on the other variables, my answer applies. In general, I don't think you are showing enough information to be explaining what your problem is. Can you show a minimal realistic example?

Comment: They do differ. That is how the rows are not duplicates. 1) The first data set contains aggregate values for each `countyGroup`, which is unique. 2) The second data set is individual values for each person. And it contain person's information on `countyGroup`, `state` and `county` (`countyGroup` uniquely identifies both `state` and `county`) . 3) My goal is to generate `state` and `county` variables in the first data set, given the unique `countyGroup`. But since there are many people who may live in the same `countyGroup`, I simply get duplicates in the resulting table.

Comment: Sorry, but my mind does not absorb these descriptions, logical though they are, no doubt. I need to be able to see and play with a realistic example.

Comment: Here are the links to my Stata files: dataset1: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/dataset1.dta  /// dataset2: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/dataset2.dta /// Actually, I think Stata lacks `map` command, which should be created in Stata 13.

Comment: Stata 13 is now announced. http://www.stata.com/stata13/ What `map` command did you think was to be included?

Comment: Something that could do similar stuff as `vlookup` in excel. (i finally found a way around by creating a temporary file, dropping the unneeded variables and duplicates). But this way has certain restrictions...

Comment: So, what were you saying, that there should be such a command in Stata, in your view? I think experienced Stata users are happy with `merge`.

Comment: I am not experienced in Stata, unfortunately. But other languages like Java, Perl, C++ do have `map`-style classes and commands.I mean like `hashmaps`, `colections`... I have implemented your answer as a way to work around my issue (dropping duplicates and using `merge`). Thanks a lot! But if there was a more complex case, i wish Stata had something like `vlookup`.

Comment: I conclude on the evidence you gave that there never was any issue at all, as a simple `merge` worked fine.