# Stata. How to split an observation?

Tags: duplicates, stata

Some observations in my data set need to be split into two or three differenet observations. For example the following observation:

```
region  income   gdp   other
North   120      450   50
```

I need to split it into three observation with **the same values** for all variables except for the region like this:

```
region  income   gdp   other
IL      120      450   50
MI      120      450   50
IN      120      450   50
```

I need something like:

```
if (region == "North") {
//create three new observations and delete the old one
}
```

Is it possible with Stata?

Comment: Where is your full `region` variable stored before you apply it? If it's in a dataset, just expand all variables and merge the two datasets on row numbers.

Comment: @Fr. thanks for reply. It is in a dataset. I am not sure what you mean by "merging the two datasets". Not all observations need to be duplicated. Only those who have the value "North" in `region` variable should be duplicated, and the value "North" must be changed for `IL, MI, IN`...I am not sure how I could merge...could you elaborate on it?

Comment: Do you have a dataset with a variable holding regions and another one holding states? If so, expand the master data as needed, sort them identically and merge using the region/state dataset on `_n`. If you provide a data extract somewhere, perhaps it would be easier to show you how this might be able to work.

Comment: @Fr. sure, here is my .dta https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/data.dta

Comment: Your dataset does not specify which region should be allocated to which state. You need to provide a list of the correspondences that you want to get. What you really want to get remains a mystery to me, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is difficult to work out the general problem here from your example. Note that

```
if region == "North" { 
      <code>
}
```

does not work as you seem to expect, as it is equivalent to

```
if region[1] == "North" { 
      <code>
}
```

and is a once-only branch. This is documented at http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/

This is legal:

```
expand 3 if region == "North"
```

but you would need to follow with one-by-one replacements.

(LATER) A wild guess is that you are following on from [Stata. How to match values in 1:m relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996481/stata-how-to-match-values-in-1m-relationship/) and trying to re-invent `merge`. All I can say is that would be a major project for an experienced Stata programmer.

(STILL LATER)

```
 gen long obsid = _n 
 gen state = "" 
 gen isnorth = region == "North" 
 expand 3 if isnorth 
 bysort obsid : replace state = "IL" if isnorth & _n == 1 
 by obsid : replace state = "MI" if isnorth & _n == 2
 by obsid : replace state = "IN" if isnorth & _n == 3
```

Comment: `expand` creates duplicates. Is there any code to leave one duplicate as it is, and modify the other two duplicates. Or it has to be done manually? Thanks

Comment: It's exactly as above, except that you don't change what you don't want to change.

Comment: (LATER) i did't think that those two questions might be related :) anyway, well, it appears that `splitting observations` is bound to be done manually after all. There is no way to prescribe `protected status` to the first duplicate, and customize the other two using `conditional structures`.

Comment: The distinction makes no sense: If you can do something "manually" in Stata, it can be programmed, if only via a `.do` file. I can't suggest specific code because I don't understand exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I am using `.do` file. OK, precisely 1) I want to split all observations in my sample that have `North` value for the `region` variable into three duplicates. 2) i want to change the values of `region` for those duplicates (to IL, MI and IN) ...

Comment: I can `expand` as you suggested, and then open the data set and manually type in : `IL`, `MI`, `IN` for those duplicates' `region`. But that is tedious and error prone.

Comment: Quite so. See my revised answer. Also check out `egen`'s `seq()` function for creating sequences 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ... followed by a once-and-for-all definion of value labels.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i was looking for. It appears that i needed that `boolean` flag.

Comment: Good. Naturally the new variable `isnorth` is not essential as you could use `region == "North"` for the same purpose.